# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Î» (U+03BB) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. while trying to knit in RMD

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex

I am trying to knit the RMD file as I need to submit it in pdf.The code are working alright when I am running it in RMD.I am getting these errors which I have no knowledge at all.

output file: BUAN6356_Homework4_Group10_1.knit.md

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Î» (U+03BB)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. For R Markdown users, see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html
Error: Failed to compile BUAN6356_Homework4_Group10_1.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See BUAN6356_Homework4_Group10_1.log for more info.
Execution halted

```
author: "Chitresh"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used this code at the start of the rmd file. Instead of using the pdf as default format ,I used Xelatex ,it worked and I was able to knit it correctly without the above error.

```
---
title: "Homework"
author: "Chitresh"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```